# Windsor DoNotWire as default setting

Tags: c#, winforms, attributes, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

How can i set this behaivor at configuration level to prevent windsor not to wire property values?

If it's known issue to prevent this at property level decorating with

```
[DoNotWire]
public IView View { get; set; }
```

is there a way to set the DoNotWire attribute at configuration level?

i'm migrating a NanoPicoContainer IoC application with thousands of properties that needs to DoNotWire.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is - [`PropertyFilter`s](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Whats-New-In-Windsor-3.ashx?NoRedirect=1&NS=Windsor#Filtering_of_property_dependencies_10)